# How to run this Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

**To the down-voters: Indicate your reasons for doing so, please. Otherwise, stop this.**

I have a java project like this:

[image]

I wish to run it. I have Eclipse. So I tried to import it into Eclipse, but failed as follows:

[image]

**Where goes wrong?**

**Update - Error Message:**

After I followed the suggestions in the comments.

[image]

Comment: import   FASTDTW-1.1.0\FASTDTW-1.1.0

Comment: Try selecting just till the FastDTW-1.1.0 folder

Comment: No still cannot work. :( Telling me how to run it in command line will also help! I am in Window. @Satya

Comment: OK do this : create a Java project in eclipse then click on Import .. general .. Archive File .. select FastDTW-1.1.0.zip and you should be through

Comment: @Satya  Error message: "Editor does not contain a main type"

Comment: its java SE project or java EE

Comment: have you tried building the project first , also what is the type of project you have created, is it is a general project or java project?

Comment: @Satya  Please see the updated screenshot.

Comment: I got it , please select the new FASTDTW-1.1.0 project and then try building it

Comment: @Satya  what does that mean? Select the FASTDTW-1.1.0 and run? Still fais.

Comment: a bit of cleanup and it should be through

Comment: OK , I have managed to do it , right click on FastDTW-1.1.0/src folder and click on Build--> Set as Source Folder . The click on Run as Java Application

Comment: "Telling me how to run it in command line will also help!": Just check the documentation for`java` and `javac`. shift+right click in folder gives the option for cmd line. And I nearly added a downvote for your new message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the root directory value to `...\FasyDTW-1.1.0\FastDTW-1.1.0\` like in this image.

[image]

This should show `FastDTW-1.1.0` in the list below. Hope this helps.

***EDIT:***

Seemed you had solved the first problem. For the second, Drag the `com` folder to the first `src` floder like in this image.

[image]

Now open all the source files to check which of them contained the `main` method. Check for the line

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

If the file you opened had this line, you can execute it. Just click the play button in the toolbar or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to run it.

***EDIT:***

For your last question: Add these lines just after the line containing `main()`

```
args = new String[]{ "Path\to\trace0.csv", "Path\to\trace1.csv", "radius" };
```

You can the path by right clicking on the file in eclipse and selecting `Properties`

Be sure to change the `radius` with your value.

Comment: Try clicking `Refresh` button

Comment: What are the contents of the folder shown in this image -- http://i.stack.imgur.com/l7vrr.png

Comment: You need to check the folders for a file called `.project` and select the folder which contained that file.

Comment: Make sure you drag the contents as shown in the above image. Then run the file that contains that line.

Comment: Thanks the dragging is really working! But one last minor problem: the main() actually takes in 2 .csv files. How may I run main(these 2 csv files) in eclipse? (In command line I can simpy type. but in eclipse after I click debug, it runs with no arguments.) the 2 .csv files are NOW in src parallel with com. THnaks!

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `main()` method?

Comment: This is the class containing main(). http://pastie.org/private/mcyyfy2ykvslxffc6iy62g

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your projects is not valid eclipse project. Try to create new eclipse project and copy your current src to new project's src.

Hope this Helps.